# Cant pass date from Javascript into HTML page

Tags: javascript, date, footer, hierarchy

So im trying to pass my date from a function in a `JS` file into my `html` web page. For some reason I keep getting the error that says 

`/*
Exception: Node cannot be inserted at the specified point in the hierarchy
@42
*/`

Help would be greatly appreciated. Here is my code.

```
function time() {       //function to add date/time stamp to the footer of the html document


var timestamp=document.getElementById("time");
var timecreation=document.createTextNode("p");
var d = new Date();
var timetextnode=document.createTextNode(d);

timecreation.appendChild(timetextnode);
timestamp.appendChild(timecreation);

}

time();
```

and the `HTML`

```
<hr size="2" width="100%">
<footer id = "time">
<p> Michael Longo web site, July 2013 </p>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var timecreation=document.createTextNode("p");
```

should be

```
var timecreation=document.createElement("p");
```

You cannot append to a text node.

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/xchxG/)